# Stored procedure only updates when running it from Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So yea. I have this really weird problem. I have the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [CP24SHOP].[sp_part_set_status_bulk]
    @user                   nvarchar(max),
    @doerTicket             VARCHAR ( 200 ) = null,
    @status                 int,
    @items                  CP24SHOP.udt_parts READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        --  Check security
        exec websocket.sp_validate_user
            @user,
            @doerTicket out

        --  foreach row in @items, update the status
        MERGE INTO [file].ItemPart WITH ( XLOCK, ROWLOCK ) AS target 
        USING ( SELECT
                    item.GID        
                FROM @items AS item
             ) AS source
        ON ( target.GID = source.GID )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                target.[Status] = @status,
                target.DateTimeModified = GETDATE();

        select 'bob'
    RETURN 0
END
```

and when I run it from Management Studio with this code

```
declare @user nvarchar(max) = 'websocket'

        DECLARE @list CP24SHOP.udt_parts
        INSERT INTO @list 
        (
            GID
        )
        VALUES  
        (
            -7228376
        )

        select [Status] from [file].ItemPart
        where GID = -7228376

        exec CP24SHOP.sp_part_set_status_bulk   
            @user = @user,
            @items = @list,
            @status = '155'

        select [Status], DateTimeModified from [file].ItemPart
        where GID = -7228376
```

it updates the `status` without problem

but when calling it through our websocket it runs the code and returns "bob" as it should, but when I check the database the status of the item hasn't updated. I'm clueless as to what might be wrong

Comment: Slight detour and not an answer to the problem at hand. But you should consider not using the sp_ prefix (or even better no prefix at all). The sp_ prefix can cause performance problems and a number of other hidden gems. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 1):

err - I think you're missing a commit.
Looks to me like you are updating & then rolling back!

Comment: in my test yes, but not from our websocket ;-)

Comment: I've removed the rollback since it seems to create more confusion than it should. When the code is run as shown above the same problem occours as before

Comment: Hmm- Could the websocket.sp_validate_user be failing silently? Sometimes I have seen certain Web Frameworks (eg NHibernate) have their own wrapper transactions that automatically add Commit/Rollback to any SQL calls - If possible I'd try and run a trace on the Websocket call.

Comment: I shouldn't, it uses the same code as all the other DB Calls and they are able to update without any problem. But it could have been the problem yes